# How to find wav file duration in php before uploading?

Tags: php, wav, duration

I need to get the wav file duration in php. I know there are lots of code examples available for this issue. I have used this one.

```
function wavDur($file) {
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
    if (fread($fp,4) == "RIFF") {
        fseek($fp, 20);
        $rawheader = fread($fp, 16);
        $header = unpack('vtype/vchannels/Vsamplerate/Vbytespersec/valignment/vbits',$rawheader);
        $pos = ftell($fp);
        while (fread($fp,4) != "data" && !feof($fp)) {
            $pos++;
            fseek($fp,$pos);
        }
        $rawheader = fread($fp, 4);
        $data = unpack('Vdatasize',$rawheader);
        $sec = $data[datasize]/$header[bytespersec];
        $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
        $seconds = intval($sec % 60);
        return str_pad($minutes,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT).":".str_pad($seconds,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

But the problem is that I need the file path the file control doesn't allow me to get the full path I want to show the duration to the user before uploading just when the user have selected the file. Is this possible?

Comment: This is not possible with php, as you would have to upload the file first. It might be possible with html5 and JavaScript.

Comment: html 5 wil have compatibilty problems with IE browser .

Comment: `Flash` could probably achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading, the file resides at user's computer, PHP script at server-side has no knowledge of the file. As such, it would not be possible to obtain any data on the file before it is being uploaded.

Comment: so is there any way else that i can get the duration of the file

Comment: Not when PHP still does not get hold of the file. So, in other words, get user to upload the file first, then display the file properties back to the user.